# Unable to use jquery control datetimepicker in velocity template (JIRA Custom field plugin)

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jira, velocity, jira-plugin

I am creating a JIRA custom field plugin and want to use below 'datetime picker' control as a 'monthyear picker' given in below link.
        http://jquerybyexample.blogspot.com/2012/06/show-only-month-and-year-in-jquery-ui.html

JIRA version is '5.2.11'

JQUERY control STUFF in velocity template:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    alert("Handler for .click() called.");  //get alert
    AJS.$("#target").click(function() {      //get alert while click on below "target" div.
        alert("Handler for .click() called.");
    });
    AJS.$(document).ready(function () {       
        AJS.$('#txtDate').datepicker({     //shows javascript error as"[object Object] has no    method 'datepicker' "              
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            dateFormat: 'MM yy',
            onClose: function () {
                var iMonth = AJS.$("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-month :selected").val();
                var iYear = AJS.$("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-year :selected").val();
                AJS.$(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(iYear, iMonth, 1));
            },
            beforeShow: function () {
                if ((selDate = AJS.$(this).val()).length > 0) {
                    iYear = selDate.substring(selDate.length - 4, selDate.length);
                    iMonth = jQuery.inArray(selDate.substring(0, selDate.length - 5), AJS.$(this).datepicker('option', 'monthNames'));
                    AJS.$(this).datepicker('option', 'defaultDate', new Date(iYear, iMonth, 1));
                    AJS.$(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(iYear, iMonth, 1));
                }
            }
        }); 
    });
    alert('final');  // not alert as error at above code
</script>
```

javascript error says as below:

> "TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'datepicker' [`http://localhost:2990/jira/s/en_US1rk3us/787/3/1/_/download/superbatch/js/batch.js:9919`"

any idea, how i could use this control in to custom field - velocity template and gets working ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to edit the file `system-webresources-plugin.xml` (should be at /atlassian-jira/WEB-INF/classes/), and add to `<web-resource key="jira-fields">` this code:

```
<resource type="download" name="jquery.min.js" location="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js">
    <param name="source" value="webContextStatic"/>
</resource>
<resource type="download" name="jquery-ui.min.js" location="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.18/jquery-ui.min.js">
    <param name="source" value="webContextStatic"/>
</resource>
```

Don't use `AJS.$` - this is Jira's internal jQuery. Using this will prevent jQuery ui from working. Try using jQuery directly:

```
$(document).ready(function () {       
     $('#txtDate').datepicker({
          .....
```

and so on..

Comment: i've updated xml file and removed inlcuding js file from velocity template but it still gives me same error ""TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'datepicker' [`http://localhost:2990/jira/s/en_US1rk3us/787/3/1/_/download/superbatch/js/batch.js:9919`" .  I've updated question above with same details.

Comment: that link in batch.js , it just a last line of pop up method in batch.js.  even, here, datepicker first object not found.. so, looks like, JS is not available stil...

Comment: when i remove AJS then it does not work. even simply keep $(document).ready(function() { alert('');} ); not worked... need to keep AJS.$  . Looks like, default velocity template variable access through '$' so..

Comment: Hi, as unable to seems jquery working, another approach , tried by using AUI CALANDER.. can you check at facing an issue : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17341989/how-can-we-change-aui-calendar-to-keep-month-and-year-only-remove-date-using-j   if we can remove calendar date and keep only month and year here and format the date MMM YYYY  using JQUERY OR any possible approach  ?  Thanks